# Extending an allocatable array with move_alloc and sourced allocation

Tags: arrays, fortran, allocation

In the following code, I am trying to increase the length of `a(:)` by first allocating a temporary array `buf(:)` of larger size, copying the contents of `a(:)` to `buf(:)`, and then using `move_alloc()` to copy the array descriptor from `buf` to `a`:

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer, allocatable :: a(:), buf(:)

    allocate( a(2) )
    a = [1,2]

    allocate( buf( 4 ), source= 0 )     !! (1)
    buf( 1:2 ) = a( 1:2 )               !! (2)

    ! allocate( buf( 4 ), source= a )   !! (3)

    ! deallocate( a )                   !! (4)
    call move_alloc( buf, a )

    print *, "a(:) = ", a(:)
end
```

Here, I have two questions: First, in line 4, is it necessary to deallocate `a(:)` explicitly before calling `move_alloc()`...? Both gfortran and Intel Fortran seem to work even without Line 4, but does this mean that `move_alloc()` automatically deallocates `a(:)` if it is pre-allocated? Second, can we replace Lines 1 and 2 by 3, i.e., use sourced allocation with different lengths of arrays? I have experimented this, and again, both gfortran and Intel Fortran seem to accept it with the (apparently) correct result.

Comment: There is also the other way `a=[a,0,0]` to reach the end point.

Comment: [Other than missing a `)` and a declaration for `i`] that final expression is fine.  The source term is a general expression (with some restrictions - loosely, not depending on things being allocated) which is evaluated once and initially.

Comment: I have tried `allocate( buf(4), source=[a,0,0] )` and `allocate( buf(4), source=[a, (0, i=3,4)] )`, and both worked fine (with no run-time errors and the correct result). This usage of [...] seems very flexible and potentially useful...

Comment: Oops, sorry comments swapped. I didn't know this syntax of array constructor (for including a whole array) up to now, so I guess I leaned a lot today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Fortran standard (2008, 13.7.118) about `move_alloc` we have the detail of the argument `to` (the second argument of the subroutine)

> It is an INTENT (OUT) argument

which matches the description you give in the link to the gfortran [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MOVE_005fALLOC.html).

As for any other dummy argument with the `intent(out)` and `allocatable` attributes the actual argument associated with `to`, then, is deallocated on invoking the subroutine `move_alloc`.  That is, you do not need to deallocate `a` yourself.

Regarding the sourced allocation, we [already know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33907377) that the array being allocated must be conformable with the source array, so that writing

```
allocate(buf(4), source=a)  ! a is the same rank as buf, but extent 2
```

is invalid, just as much as

```
allocate(buf(4), source=a(1:2))
```

is.

However, whilst there are some numbered constraints about sourced allocation this conformable requirement doesn't feature in one of those.  So, your compiler isn't required to detect that your code is non-conforming.

Naturally, a compiler is *allowed* to complain, as you see when using `a(1:2)` as the source.  To some degree, it is much easier at compile-time to see that an array of extent 4 is not conformable with `a(1:2)` than the case of `a`.  You can experiment with, say, `a(1:SIZE(a))` to see just how much effort your compiler takes with such tests.

As a final comment, one can of course replace your lines 1 and 2 with a single sourced allocation:

```
allocate(buf, source=[a,0,0])  ! Buf is 2 longer than a
```

But that's not necessarily "better".

Comment: @francescalus Thanks very much for detailed explanation. I didn't know that if a dummy argument has both the ALLOCATABLE and INTENT(OUT), the actual argument will be deallocated automatically (if necessary). Indeed, this is the first time that I experienced this situation, because I used ALLOCATABLE dummies only for "fresh allocation" of still un-allocated arrays (in my other programs).

Comment: As for sourced allocation, I tried several other patterns after reading your explanation. First, I compiled `allocate( buf(4), source=a )` with `gfortran -fcheck=all`, then it gave run-time error about array bounds. So it seems that allocate() tries to read a(3) and a(4) to copy them to buf(3:4). On the other hand, `ifort -check all` did not give run-time error for `source=a` (apparently filling 0 for buf(3:4)), so the behavior seems different for this non-conforming code.

Comment: Next, both for `allocate( buf(4), source=a(1:size(a)) )` and `allocate( buf(4), source=a(:) )`, ifort did not complain anything when no option is given, but it gave run-time error when -check all was specified. The behavior of gfortran was also similar (raised run-time error with -fcheck=all). So this is essentially the same as the problem of overrunning array bounds... So I think I now understand the behavior. Thanks very much :)

Comment: @roygvib Yes, my comments on the sourced allocation were really about compile-time checks.  As you say, with run-time checking enabled there is the usual array of bounds tests.  It's interesting that ifort doesn't notice this bounds violation/has an alternative approach (either of which is entirely legitimate).

Answer (score 2):

The Fortran standard is written so that you don't have to wory about memory leaks with allocatables. If the operation is not forbidden in the first place, it should not cause any leaks. This rule holds for any possible standard conforming operations with allocatable variables.

So, as the Intel manual states, the `to` argument will be deallocated first.

Comment: It may be usefol for someone, but franvescalus's answer is more rigorous. I wilk leave is as a supplying information. I started to write this before his answer appeared.

Comment: Thanks very much for your info. I think it is reassuring that no memory leak occurs in this way. And is it also okay to assume that no leak occurs even when we use array pointers in  Fortran? or is it a different story and the above safe behavior  comes only for allocatable arrays...?  (I guess the latter will be the case.)

Comment: There are many ways how to cause memory leaks or program crashes with pointers. They are a different story.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it necessary to deallocate `a(:)`:

**Update** I misread your question. You are asking about the `TO` section.

I just tried it out with `valgrind`, and it seems as if the `deallocate` is not necessary to prevent leaks. But I'd probably still do it, just to be on the safe side.

Second question:

> [Can we] ... use sourced allocation with different lengths of arrays?

According to my trusted [Fortran Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071285784), no:

> [The] ... array being allocated must be conformable with (have the same rank and shape as) the source array or expression.

Then again, my book does not cover standards beyond 2003, so things might be different for Fortran 2008 or Fortran 2015.

Comment: Thanks very much for your info. Yes, I was asking about the TO part. I had checked gfortran's [man page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MOVE_005fALLOC.html) but there was no enough info. So I was afraid about memory leak... I also found Intel's [page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/526469), which says that the TO part is deallocated, but sometimes ifort is too generous, so I was wondering if it's also a common behavior for other compilers.

Comment: As for sourced allocation, I also tried something like `allocate( buf( 4 ), source= a(1:2) )`, but then both compilers did complain that the shape of arrays is different. It is interesting why the compilers do not raise the error if the colon is not used in the source part...